# Websites that uses Synchronous method dispatch vs Asynchronous method dispatch

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm currently writing a paper on Asynchronous vs Synchronous calls from a users perspective. It's in short what the user prefers the most of the two techniques. I was wondering if there are any good websites i can use in my testing of this?
If anyone has any good examples to give i would be very thankfull for that!
Or do i have to develop these sites myself with the calls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean websites using ajax with "asynchronous websites"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is does not directly relate to a programming problem. SO is meant for programming questions, not for other more general questions which are loosely connected to programming. Moreover, this question can be seen as asking for recommendations for a specific type of website. This is a too broad question and thus it is likely to attract opinionated answers.

Comment: You first need to clarify what you meant by asynchronous site. I can think of at least three different definitions of what asynchronous could mean in terms of a website interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is almost impossible to compare two different websites using different technologies, because the difference of the website, e.g. user interface design, is more important than ajax vs classic request-response.

However, here is the answer:

Most purely information **giving** websites where the information does not change frequently (e.g. your financial department or city information, university main page, non-online-shop commercial information pages, ...) are usually classic request-response.

Good examples for websites using ajax are facebook and stackoverflow. Even google uses ajax on their main search website (you type your search phrase and while you type, without hitting enter, you see the results). Many websites which **take** information from the user use ajax because taking information often needs a response back from the server to the user and this response for user input can be made to feel much smoother using ajax compared to non-ajax (classic request-response).

**BUT** the sole fact that a website allows the user to give input to the website (or the absence of such a functionality) does not tell you if the website uses ajax or not. It's just that this is one example of a functionality where ajax is very suitable to enhance the user experience.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, this paper i'm writing, there is no real way of testning the different technologies at all? It seems to me that there can be no comparising since the different websites serve completly different purposes, it's like static and dynamic pages? I was planning on doing some user testing and then analyse the data i collect from them buy testing which they prefer.

Comment: You can do the research for this paper in a way so the results are correct, even with different websites, but if you wanted to, you could also cheat by selecting bad ajax-websites and good non-ajax websites and then your results would show that non-ajax websites give a better user experience. What I want to say is that it is difficult to prove the correctness of your results.

Comment: I appriciate your answer Daniel! I

Comment: I did not want to discourage you at all. Sorry if that happened. Also the close vote is not meant to discourage you in any way. I would not have written such a long answer if I had not liked the question. There might be another stackexchange network site which suits your question perfectly well. Have a look and maybe move your question to another site here: http://stackexchange.com/sites#